# AutoMapper - Unable to include GetUserDto in response

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

AutoMapper Profile:

```cs
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Character, GetCharacterDto>();
        CreateMap<AddCharacterDto, Character>();
        CreateMap<Weapon, GetWeaponDto>();
        CreateMap<User, GetUserDto>();
    }
}
```

Service Layer:

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResponse<GetCharacterDto>> GetSingle(int id)
{
    var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<GetCharacterDto>();
    var dbCharacter = await _context.Characters
    .Include(c => c.User)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(ele => ele.Id == id && ele.User.Id == 1);
    serviceResponse.Data = _mapper.Map<GetCharacterDto>(dbCharacter);
    return serviceResponse;
}
```

`GetCharacterDto` Class:

```cs
public class GetCharacterDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Frodo";
    public int HitPoints { get; set; } = 100;
    public int Strength { get; set; } = 10;
    public int Defense { get; set; } = 10;
    public int Intelligence { get; set; } = 10;
    public RpgClass Class { get; set; } = RpgClass.Knight;
    public GetUserDto User = new GetUserDto();
}
```

`GetUserDto` Class:

```cs
public class GetUserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "string",
    "hitPoints": 0,
    "strength": 10,
    "defense": 0,
    "intelligence": 0,
    "class": 0
  },
  "success": true,
  "message": ""
}
```

Response data is of model `GetCharacterDto` which has `GetUserDto` but in the response, the `User` object is not included. I am not sure what's going wrong here. Can anyone help me with the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GetCharacterDto` class, `User` is a field but not a property.

Change it to the property by adding getter and setter.

```cs
public class GetCharacterDto
{
    ...

    public GetUserDto User { get; set; } = new GetUserDto();
}
```